How are these two definitions of $e^x$ equivalent?
How these to definitions of $e^x$ equivalent?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{xn}= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$
I just can't prove that they are the same, so how do you do it?

Substitute $n \to n/x$.

This question is similar to: prove the definitions of e to be equivalent.  If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You simply cannot write $$(1+\frac{1}{n})^{x \ n}$$ for integer n and real or complex $x$ without having defined real positive $a^b$ first.  That implies the definition of $e^x$ and its inverse $\log x$

@Roland: $a^b$ can be defined as the limit of $a^{b_n}$ where $(b_n)$ is any sequence of rationals that tends to $b$. You dont need $e$ at all.

Existence is easy,  but you need the value and  summation formula of exponents; possible to do but not recommended.
